# Microseconds delay

Tags: c#, .net, delay

I need to delay some piece of code from processing for some time in Microseconds.
I tried a lots of things such as thread.Sleep(x), but it has only milliseconds resolution.

I am using .NET 2.0 in MS Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Why are you using .net 2 in 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
```

allows you to get very small (few nanosecond) ticks, which you can convert to microseconds using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx). Then you can just let an empty `while` loop for as long as you need.

Edit: and it even is supported by .NET 2.0.

Comment: You should probably use [`Thread.SpinWait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx) instead of an empty `while` loop because *"The code SpinWait executes is designed to prevent problems that can occur on computers with multiple processors"*.